# How to debug with createJS's objects

Tags: easeljs, createjs

I am using `createJS` for a game, but when I debug the code with `console`, I got all objects displayed as an `a`. Then I have no idea what the object really is.

[image]

What does the `a` here mean? And what's the best way to debug these code?

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the minified source. Instead, use the combined source. You can get a combined version of each library in GitHub, which is one file containing all the classes, but just appended, instead of minified.

If you are using the full combined suite on the CDN, then you can change the path to `.combined` instead of `.min`: https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2014.12.12.combined.js

Cheers.

Comment: That solved the problem, thank you! But I still have a question: did the minifying process change all Constructor's name to the same one? How could that happen?

Comment: Yes, the minifier rewrites the original constructor, so instead of `function Sprite() {}`, it will be something like `function a() {}`.

Comment: Note: the build process has changed to prevent all class names from minification. Future versions will have class names in all combined files. Thanks for bringing this up!